# Qual a diferença entre as chamadas open() e opendir() no UNIX?

Tags: c, api, arquivo, diretório, unix

Se para a abertura de arquivos utiliza-se a chamada de sistema `open()`, porque existe outra chamada de sistema pra abertura de arquivos diretório (`opendir()`), se um diretório é um tipo de arquivo? Não era pra ser uma chamada só pra todo tipo de arquivo?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Em tese poderia mas você teria que filtrar o que é diretório ou não, poderia errar ou não se atentar para todos os detalhes. A [`opendir`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/opendir.html) trata um diretório de forma mais específica. É essencialmente um facilitador em relação ao [`open`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html) para uma situação específica.

Answer (score 0):

Até onde eu sei `open` abre todos os tipos de arquivos, menos diretórios.

Já `opendir` retorna DIR* do diretório aberto que é passado pro `readdir()` pra ler seu conteúdo.